# Mount Rails Admin with path set in environment variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, rails-admin

[Rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) is mounted like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
  ...
end
```

When I try to set the admin path as an environment variable like so:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => ENV['ADMIN_PATH'], as: 'rails_admin'
  ...
end
```

I get the following exception:

```
.../ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:507:in 
  `mount': A rack application must be specified (RuntimeError)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Are you sure that your `ENV` is set at the time you try to mount the route?